# Generate JSON type definition file with Tern.js's condense utility

Tags: node.js, tern

I'm trying to use Tern's [condense](https://github.com/ternjs/tern/blob/master/bin/condense) script to generate a type definition file for the [p5.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/p5.js/) Javascript library.

The Tern documentation says:
"Pass --plugin name or --plugin name={jsonconfig} to load plugins. Use --def file to load JSON definitions."

I put the p5.js source code in the project's root and ran `node condense --plugin ../p5/p5.js`

I'm getting reference errors for all `window`, `screen`, and `document`-related functions, which makes me think the command is trying to run p5.js files, not analyze them.

Am I structuring the command incorrectly? Do I need a .tern-project file for this?

Comment: `--plugin` is for tern's server plugins. You use them for instance to resolve `require()` and `import` in the library you want to condense. You can try `condense ../p5/p5.js` without using any plugins. The documentation doesn't go into detail about how this works, so it's hard to troubleshoot when things go wrong.

Comment: It is treating p5.js as a plugin the syntax is `node condense --plugin {pluginName} fileName` eg `node condense --plugin angular ../p5/p5.js`